# How to get all documents from Firestore in once?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I subscribe to valueChanges I first get back an object of length 1, as you can see in console.log (picture below), and a short time later the object with all values. But this is not what I wanted. I need go get all values from the beginning so that I can continue to work with these. Can somebody help? Thanks.

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
   this.store.collection('Kontaktdaten',ref => ref.where('Ankunft', '>=', timeAnkunft))
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe((persons) => {
          personsArray = persons;
          console.log(personsArray)
          personsArray.map((person,index,array) => {
            if(person.Ende > timeEndeBesuch) {
              array.splice(index,1);
            }
          })
          resolve(personsArray);   
        })
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable disk caching by any chance? If so, it is likely that the initial result comes from the local cache.

There isn't really a way to prevent this, but you can detect that the item comes from the local cache and may be stale by checking its [`DocumentSnapshot.metadata.fromCache` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata#fromcache).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The first object definitely comes from the cache. No, I have not consciously enabled disk caching. However, I believe this is enabled by default on mobile apps? How can I disable the disk caching?

Comment: On native mobile clients it is enabled by default, but since you tagged with `angular` I assumed you're using the web/JavaScript SDK. Either way, to change the offline persistence toggle from its default value see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence